# storing values in dynamically created variable names

Tags: python

If I were to **read** 10 input files and store them in variable names `file1`, `file2`, `file3` etc that are dynamically created inside a for loop using string concatenation, how would I store the values in them?
For example,

```
'file'+'1'=pandas.read_csv(...)
```

doesn't work.
What are the alternatives to create variables dynamically to store values that are available dynamically?

Comment: Just use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) and store your file 'names' as keys and your CSV readers as values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use a `dict` structure:

```
datasets = {}
for i in range(10):
    key = "file{}".format(i)
    datasets[key] = pd.read_csv(...)
```